# How to take advantage of the information/structure we have in the labels in multiple output regression?

Tags: supervised-learning, structured-prediction, multiple-response

I have a regression problem where each observation possesses a vector of features and 4 associated responses.

These responses, as in many problems are correlated. It would be nice to be able to predict them "all at once" in order to take into account that correlation and the structure that they possess. This would also possible enable the learned model to generalize better.

Now, neural networks naturally takes the correlation and structure into account as the earlier layers are connected to all the responses at once. The RFs on sci-kit learn can also predict all the responses using a single forest.

Would implementing the following make sense at all?

Imagine I have 3 responses y1, y2, y3 and the feature vector x and I am interested in predicting y1 (while trying to take into account the other responses). I would:

1) train a model with [x,y2,y3] concatenated to predict y1. And another model
2) train with x to predict y1, y2, y1 in turn separately. Then on test,

3) Take my x_test and use my model in 2) to predict all the responses separately and then use my trained model in 1) to predict y1. I then end up with two predictions for y1 that I could combine.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If that's a linear regression problem, I think using partial least squares (PLS) or canonical correlation analysis (CCA) will give you satisfied answer. Those techniques takes into account the correlations between the responses.

If that's a non-linear regression problem, the nonlinear version or those techniques would work.

But if you want to apply neural networks, I think using a regular multi-layer perceptron with what you decribed as method (1) would suffice, if you are only interested in predicting y1.